# vim match for complete html tags

Tags: html, vim, tags, match

Helllaw world?

```
<font color=red><font color=red>I am stupid</font></font>
```

We can see that `<font color=red>` is duplicated, so I can delete it by a command

```
:%s,<font color=red>\(<font color=red>[^<]*</font>\)</font>,\1,g
```

However, for the lines

```
<font color=red><font color=red>I am <b>stupid</b>, Huh.</font></font>
<font color=red><font color=red>I am <span style="something"><font color=blue>stupid</font>, Huh.</span></font></font>
```

The above command does not work.

So I imagined that I would be happy, if there were some escape character, for example '\Q', such that '\Q' matches any html tag complete words. Here, the tag complete words means that

```
I am <b>stupid</b>, Huh.
I am <span style="something"><font color=blue>stupid</font>, Huh.</span>
I am <br> <font color=red><img src="me.html"></font> <br>
<u><a href="you.html">You</a></u> are <b><font color=red>smarter</font></b> than me
```

lines are tag complete words, because above four lines have no unmatched tags. All the opened tags are closed completely, by this reason, above four lines are tag complete words lines by my definition.

Then if I wanted to delete the leading tag `<font color=red>` for following line.

```
 <font color=red><font color=red>I am <b>stupid</b>, Huh.</font></font>
```

I can use the following command.

```
 :%s,<font color=red>\(<font color=red>\Q*</font>\)</font>,\1,g
```

Is there '\Q' like wild card in vim?

If '\Q' wild card exists, then by typing '/\Q' we can easily find unmatched tags (that is, not-closed tags and not-opened tags)

Comment: not able to fully understand your question... to remove immediately repeating tags, you can use `:%s/\(<[^>]*>\)\1/\1/g`

Comment: Dear sundeep, I must have to delete the closing tag also. You only removed opening tag.

Comment: did you miss the `g` flag? it doesn't care where the tags are... `<font color=red><font color=red>` or `</font></font>`

Comment: Dear sundeep, I missed g flags. However your command does not work for `<span a><span a>something <span b><span c>some </span></span>something</span></span>`

Comment: can you add that example input with expected output to question? so that it'll help others trying to suggest an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for information.

I am the person who asked above original question.

I wrote following code.

```
let g:position=[0,0,0,0]
function! SetQQ(arg_0, arg_1, arg_2, arg_3)
        let g:position[0] = a:arg_0
        let g:position[1] = a:arg_1
        let g:position[2] = a:arg_2
        let g:position[3] = a:arg_3
        call setpos('.', g:position)
endfunction

let     g:xxcmd_find_pair_escape = "normal vat\<ESC>"
let     g:xxcmd_find_pair = "normal vat"
let     g:xxcmd_escape_me = "normal \<Esc>"
let     g:xxcmd_del_out = "normal hda>`<da>"

function! PairOnePrivate(command, pattern)
        let     xxcmd_onn="normal lda>"
        let     xxcmd_all="normal hdat"
        let     s:mycount=0

        let     curr_c = col(".")
        let     my_line = line(".")
        let     cmd_done = 0

        while 1 
                let where_a = match(getline(my_line), a:pattern, curr_c - 1)
                if (where_a < 0 )
                        echo "POP(): NOTHING and BREAK at=" getline(my_line)
                        break
                endif

                let next_search_position = matchend(getline(my_line), a:pattern, curr_c - 1)

                call SetQQ(0, my_line, where_a+1, 0)
                exec g:xxcmd_find_pair_escape

                if ((my_line==line(".")) && (col(".") == where_a+1))
                        let     curr_c = next_search_position
                        exec g:xxcmd_escape_me
                        exec xxcmd_onn
                        echo "POP(): XXX There is no matching tag at line " line(".")
                        break
                endif

                if (a:command == 0)
                        echo "POP(): DELETE ALL"
                        exec xxcmd_all
                        let cmd_done = 1
                else
                        echo "POP(): DELETE OUTER"
                        exec g:xxcmd_del_out
                        let cmd_done = 1
                endif
                let s:mycount += 1
        endwhile 
        return cmd_done
endfunction


function! PairOne(command, pattern)
        let     target = "<.[^>]*"

        if (a:pattern !~ target)
                echo "PairOne(): " a:pattern "args should begin with <"
                return
        endif

        call PairOnePrivate(a:command, a:pattern)
endfunction
```

Whenever I wanted to delete `<span>` for following line,

```
Something <span>something <b>Something</b> Something</span>
```

I used

```
:g/<span>/call PairOne(1, @/)
```

I think I could find answer of my original question by changing the `PairOne()`. But I hate to code the `PairOne()`.